# Audio Jack detection backwards

Tags: windows-7, audio, speakers

I have a HP Envy with widows 7. The external speakers not working. When I plug in the headphones Beats Audio says 'You just unplugged a device from the audio jack' , when I unplug the headphones it says 'you just plugged a device into the audio jack'. When the headphones are plugged they work, I hear sound or music. Is this a registry problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: You appear to have created 2 accounts. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again? Please don't do that, read and take note of [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers) instead of asking the same question again. If you have new information you should edit it into the original question instead of asking a new one.

Comment: Duplicate: [Audio Jack Detection](http://superuser.com/q/1060275)

Answer (score 0):

Open Realtek manager,
click speakers,
Right click green button (that is my connection yours may be different),
Choose "connector retasking"
at the bottom of the page you will see "enable auto popup dialog",
Disable it and you are set to go.